# How to set a server side validation for mobile number did not start with zero in asp.net 3.5?

Tags: asp.net

I have done it using javascript. But i have to do it on server side.

```
function Validate()    
    {
       var x = ctl00_txtMobileno.value;
       if (x.charAt(0)=="0" || x.length !=10 || isNaN(x)||x.indexOf(" ")!=-1)
       {
            alert("Enter correct 10 digit mobile number. It should not start with Zero !!");
            ctl00_txtMobileno.focus();
            return false;
       }

    }
```

Comment: And? What happens? You've said what you're trying to do. You've shown us the code. You haven't told us why the code doesn't fit your requirement. Do you get an error?

Comment: What did you try in asp.net ? Can you share this code too ?

Comment: Sir, I have to do the above validation using regular expression in asp.net.
.
Because, the above code is not working in mozilla firefox.